# Javascript on Firefox stops execution unexpectedly on an onchange assignment

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

The following javascript code snippets runs perfectly on Google Chrome but doesn't continue before the second alert on Firefox:

**`init.js`:**

```
function __init__() {
    alert("welcome!");
    document.getElementById("myselector").onchange = foo;
    alert("must go here");

    // some other initialization code goes here

    alert("must end here");
}

window.onload = __init__;
```

**`foo.js`:**

```
function foo() {
    // some other code for function foo
    break;
    // the rest of the code
}
```

There were no errors reported by the Firefox or Chrome's Developer Tool Console however, keeping me frustrated for days.

Comment: Made alerts instead of `console.log` statements because of laziness. Sorry about that :P

Comment: *"There were no errors reported by the Firefox or Chrome's Developer Tool Console however, keeping me frustrated for days."* With the code above, yes, there are: Chrome says *"Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement"*. Firefox says *"SyntaxError: unlabeled break must be inside loop or switch"*. I'd be very interested to see the code you claim failed silently, because I suspect the error was caught and suppressed by other code in your page/app.

Comment: @ badwolf: If you go into it, I'm sure you'll find that you're catching an exception and not reporting it or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove any `break` statement when not using it inside loops or `switch` statements.